# ora2pg - Strawberry perl - Can't load module Oracle.xs.dll

Tags: oracle, strawberry-perl, ora2pg

When i try to launch the following line :

```
ora2pg -t SHOW_VERSION -c config/ora2pg.conf
```

I get the following error :

> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load 'C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.xs.dll' for module DBD::Oracle: load_file:Le module spécifié est introuvable at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
>     at (eval 15) line 3.
>
> Compilation failed in require at (eval 15) line 3.
>
> Perhaps a required
>   shared library or dll isn't installed where expected  at
>   C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib/Ora2Pg.pm line 1552.

I'm using Strawberry perl 5.28, 64bit.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding the Oracle directory in the PATH.

Comment: please let us know which Oracle directory path have you added, because I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

For connect to Oracle database you must have *Oracle client* with **OCI.dll** accessible to be dynamically loaded by **Oracle.xs.dll**. So, if you haven't any *Oracle client* installed then from the Oracle web site download the ***Oracle instant client***, the same 32/64-bit edition like your *Strawberry* edition is, unpack it somewhere, where you want to store it (e.g. C:\Progs\OracleInstantClient), and add directory containing **OCI.dll** to the **PATH** environment variable. Then it should works.